# How secondary index scan works in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

InnoDB has two types of indexes: primary (clustered), and secondary (with pimary index key).

When I type query that scan fields indexed by secondary index my question starts.
Is InnoDB scan secondary index and retrive one by one records that hit condition? 
If I have 50 hits in secondary index InnoDB seek 50 times primary index?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is InnoDB scan secondary index and retrive one by one records that hit condition?

If you select columns not covered by the secondary index, then yes, it should retrieve them from the table (the clustered index).

If you have this layout:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ca INT NOT NULL, cb INT NOT NULL, KEY(ca))

SELECT  cb
FROM    a
WHERE   ca = $some_value
```

the following happens:

1. Using a `B-Tree seek`, `InnoDB` finds the first record in the index on `ca` which holds `$some_value`
2. It then traverses the index, taking records one by one, until it finds the first record greater than `$some_value`.
3. Since only `ca` (key column) and `id` (row pointer) are contained in the index, `InnoDB` needs to find values of `cb` in the table itself.
4. For each record in the index, it takes the value of `id` and searches the table for it. Since the table is in fact a clustered index on `id`, `B-Tree` search is used for that.

However, if you have this query:

```
SELECT  ca, id
FROM    a
WHERE   ca = $some_value
```

, then everything can be retrieved right from the index, and steps `3` and `4` are not performed. It is shown in the query plan as `using index`.

> If I have 50 hits in secondary index InnoDB seek 50 times primary index?

Yes (with regard to the comment above)